# MySQL query in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Is possible to get all items with name = "A" AND status = 1? Name is in table items and status is in table status.

Something like `SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = "A" AND id AS status.itemid = 1` but this does not work.

Db structure:

TABLE items:

```
id      name
1       A
2       A
3       B
```

TABLE status:

```
itemid      status
1           1
2           1
3           2
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = "A" AND status = 1` ?  ah 2 tables nvm

Comment: Thanks but status column is not in items table. It is in sigle table with same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use inner join

```
select a.name, b.status 
from  items as a 
inner join status as b  on a.id = b.itemid
where a.name ='A' and b.status =1;
```

Comment: thank you very much and sorry for stupid question but this is my first time when i have to use inner join so now I will know next time :)

Comment: Do not apologize .. I do not think there are stupid questions in this area .. just some things already have the answers others are still trying and SO is a step in this very popular search .. anyway if my answer is right  .. please mark it as accepted .